# Unauthenticated Proxy Settings

Tags: networking, internet, proxy

I am trying to setup a Manual Proxy to bypass the login portal page, it works fine with synaptics-package manager an firefox but when trying to apply it to the main Network Proxy, it doesnt take any effect i have tried changing 
/etc/environment

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
http_proxy=http://172.16.15.253:4647/    
https_proxy=http://172.16.15.253:4647/    
ftp_proxy=http://172.16.15.253:4647/    
no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.1"    
HTTP_PROXY=http://172.16.15.253:4647/    
HTTPS_PROXY=http://172.16.15.253:4647/     
FTP_PROXY=http://172.16.15.253:4647/   
NO_PROXY="localhost,127.0.0.1"
```

/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/95proxies

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://172.16.15.253:4647/";    
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://172.16.15.253:4647/";   
Acquire::https::proxy "https://172.16.15.253:4647/";
```

I am unable to update my packages and I have tried searching it on Youtube and Other Platforms bu no way seems to be working for unauthicanted proxy settings.
Please Help and thanks

Comment: the output for echo $https_proxy and traceroute google.com is
https://:@172.16.15.253:4645/ and traceroute google.com

I followed step by step but still it is not working. Curl is not returning anything. I cannot access internet via terminal, firefox works just fine

Comment: Nope it doesnot require anything 
172.15.15.253 and port is 4647 
that's it